# php redirecting to another page showing wrong results

Tags: php, xml

I've been trying to verify login info with data stored in an xml file using php. If the email id and password don't match, it's supposed to echo an error message saying "sorry they don't match". If they match, the user is supposed to be redirected to index.html. My code keeps showing the error message even if I try to log in with the correct email and password.
My html form:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<input id='email1' type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress" required="required" class="input-txt" onchange="checkuser();"  /> &nbsp;
<input id='pass1' type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" class="input-txt" />
<button type="submit" class="btn" name="ok" id="b1" >Sign in </button> <br> <br>
```

my xml file(storedata.xml):

```
<document>
<data><fname>Group</fname><lname>Project</lname><email2>webuy55@gmail.com</email2><pass2>teamproject55</pass2></data>
<data><fname>Sam</fname><lname>Kim</lname><email2>samkim@gmail.com</email2><pass2>abcd1234</pass2></data>
<data><fname>Harold</fname><lname>Pain</lname><email2>hpain@gmail.com</email2><pass2>abcd</pass2></data>
<data><fname>Ryan</fname><lname>Reynold</lname><email2>ryan@gmail.com</email2><pass2>123456</pass2></data>
<data><fname>Reece</fname><lname>Simpson</lname><email2>reece@gmail.com</email2><pass2>onlinestore</pass2></data>
<data><fname>Stefani</fname><lname>Germanotta</lname><email2>stef@gmail.com</email2><pass2>bbbcccddd</pass2></data>
</document>
```

my php code(login.php) :

```
<?php 
$emailid= $_POST["email"];
$pass= $_POST["password"];
if(isset($_REQUEST['ok'])) {
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file('storedata.xml');
foreach($xml2->data as $user) { // for every user node
    if($user->email2 == $emailid && $user->pass2 == $pass) {
       header("Location: index.html", true, 301);
       exit();
    }
    else {
        echo 'Sorry, email and passwords dont match.<br>
        <p>Please go back to the login page and enter correct information.</p>';
        break;
    }
}
if (($_POST["email"]== "webuy55@gmail.com") && ($_POST["password"]== "teamproject55"))
{
header("Location: backstore_inventory_ben.html", true, 301);
exit();
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your foreach loop, you are only checking the first entry in the XML data, then bailing out if it is not a match. You need to do something like this:

```
<?php
$emailid = $_POST["email"];
$pass    = $_POST["password"];
if (isset($_REQUEST['ok']))
{
    $xml2 = simplexml_load_file('storedata.xml');
    $validLogin = false;
    foreach ($xml2->data as $user)
    {
        // for every user node
        if ($user->email2 == $emailid && $user->pass2 == $pass)
        {
            $validLogin = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($validLogin)
    {
        header("Location: index.html", true, 301);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Sorry, email and passwords dont match.<br><p>Please go back to the login page and enter correct information.</p>';
    }
    
    if (($_POST["email"] == "webuy55@gmail.com") && ($_POST["password"] == "teamproject55"))
    {
        header("Location: backstore_inventory_ben.html", true, 301);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Also, if you are going to have more than a few entries in your XML file, you may want to check out [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom) and specifically [DOMXpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) so you can search for a match without having to iterate through the whole ist and do string matching.